# Why can't I get any result via P/Invoke but exit immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I need to develop a program working with hardware via its C++ sdk by Winform of .Net7.

I try to achieve this by `P/Invoke`.

Here is its interface definition of the hardware:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

And here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            var i = new MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST();
            var j = MV_CODEREADER_EnumDevices(ref i, 1);
        }
        [DllImport("MvCodeReaderCtrl.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 MV_CODEREADER_EnumDevices(ref MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST pstDevList, UInt32 nTLayerType);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_USB3_DEVICE_INFO
    {
        public byte CrtlInEndPoint;
        public byte CrtlOutEndPoint;
        public byte StreamEndPoint;
        public byte EventEndPoint;
        public UInt16 idVendor;
        public UInt16 idProduct;
        public uint nDeviceNumber;
        public byte chDeviceGUID;
        public byte chVendorName;
        public byte chModelName;
        public byte chFamilyName;
        public byte chDeviceVersion;
        public byte chManufacturerName;
        public byte chSerialNumber;
        public byte chUserDefinedName;
        public uint nbcdUSB;
        public fixed uint nReserved[3];
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_GIGE_DEVICE_INFO
    {
        public UInt32 nIpCfgOption;
        public UInt32 nIpCfgCurrent;
        public UInt32 nCurrentIp;
        public UInt32 nCurrentSubNetMask;
        public UInt32 nDefultGateWay;
        public fixed byte chManufacturerName[32];
        public fixed byte chModelName[32];
        public fixed byte chDeviceVersion[32];
        public fixed byte chManufacturerSpecificInfo[48];
        public fixed byte chSerialNumber[16];
        public fixed byte chUserDefinedName[16];
        public UInt32 nNetExport;
        public UInt32 nCurUserIP;
        public fixed uint nReserved[3];
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO
    {
        public UInt16 nMajorVer;
        public UInt16 nMinorVer;
        public uint nMacAddrHigh;
        public uint nMacAddrLow;
        public uint nTLayerType;
        public fixed uint nReserved[3];
        public MV_CODEREADER_GIGE_DEVICE_INFO stGigEInfo;
        public MV_CODEREADER_USB3_DEVICE_INFO stUsb3VInfo;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    public struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST
    {
        public UInt32 nDeviceNum;
        public MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO[] pDeviceInfo;
    }

    }
}
```

After the program runs, it exits immediately without any error.

Even if I wrap the code with try&catch, it still cannot catch any error.

What's wrong with my code? This is my first contact with C++, I don't know if the variable I declared is wrong

Comment: Is the form displayed at all? Unless this is your application's main form, it won't be displayed. Instead of trying to use WinForms, create a console application and test just the API calls

Comment: All your uses of "string" is wrong. An "unsigned char" is "byte" in C#. You will also have to decorate the struct with "[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=0)]". And then you cannot use "uint[]" since that will be a managed array. You should use "fixed uint nReserved[3]". Just to begin with. In short you're in for a real treat here...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried test it in ConsoleApp and now it reports an error with System.ExecutionEngineException(Cannot evaluate the exception source)

Comment: Since you seem to be using a GigE vision SDK, have you tried a existing .Net wrapper? Admittedly most are still for .Net framework, but might still work in newer .net versions. And several SDK providers are working on support for .net 5+.

Comment: @DanByström I fixed all you said while VS reports an error with 'public fixed uint nReserved[3];'. Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: @JonasH The SDK of the hardware is made by .Net framework 2.0. I have asked their company for the SDK for .NET 7, but they said that they cannot provide non-.NET FRAMEWORK SDK for the time being. So I have to develop it with its C++ SDK now.

Comment: @MelonNG did they now? Because .NET Framework 2.0 is out of support for a long, long time now. The oldest supported version is 4.6.2. If you bought that SDK because they claimed they have a .NET SDK, they probably need to return the money. Or provide a fix. Or better yet, the source code, so *you* can compile it for .NET 7 if they are too lazy to do what you paid them for

Comment: .Net 7 can load libraries for .Net framework. It may not always work, especially not for an ancient .net 2.0 library, but it can be worth a try. Also, if the hardware follows the standard you can use any GigE/genicam SDK that not specifically locked to some brand.

Comment: @JonasH not just ancient - unsupported. That implies liability, if they knowingly sold unsupported software. Of course, most of the time hardware vendors just copy a reference driver and SDK and just change the version fields, so using a generic SDK may be the best option

Comment: @JonasH I tried this before. When I reference it VS reports error and the .Net SDK sometimes doesn't work with P/Invoke. So I have to achieve this by its C++ SDK.

Comment: Also, if you are using windows, I would use C++/CLI for any kind of complicated native API, since that lets you do the conversions yourself, without needing intimate knowledge about how the marshaller works.

Comment: You need to be in "unsafe" mode to declare fixed size buffers. https://www.dotnetstuffs.com/c-fixed-size-buffer/

Comment: @JonasH My program will run cross-platform (via Avalonia), and it also provides a Linux SDK (similar to the C++ SDK). I just run it in Winform for testing convenience.

Comment: Then you will need to learn how to construct types to allow the marshaller to convert between managed and unmanaged data. That is not a skill I posses, and from browsing the documentation is seem complicated. I would create a native library just for learning / testing, so that I could gradually test more complicated calls/types in isolation. Since you are likely making a whole bunch of mistakes all at once.

Comment: @JonasH I'm just going to have to try and learn because I have no other way to manipulate this device using .Net.

Comment: @DanByström I updated my code and fixed all the problems you mentioned while it still exits immediately after running.

Comment: I'm very sorry for my bad copy-and-paste. It must of course be Pack=1. 

Comment: @DanByström I update my code from Pack=0 to Pack=1. Now it runs with error:An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Unknown Module. Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: You still have a problem here:
public MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO[] pDeviceInfo
according to the doc it should be a POINTER:
public MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO* pDeviceInfo

Comment: @DanByström An embedded array should be marshalled as a pointer by default?

Comment: @Charlieface Oh, I didn't know that. Apparently I go lower level than I need to. 

Comment: @DanByström And now how can I fix my code? I looked for some pointer usage, but I don't quite understand how to use it here.

Comment: I would just have initialized a struct,, say x, and then pointed pDeviceInfo to it. pDeviceInfo = &x. If you need several, you initialize an array and then take the address of the first one. But all of this is very tricky. Have you considered putting all of this in a C++/CLI wrapper? That would solve your marshalling troubles, but would admittedly give you deployment trouble in the future... :-(

Comment: @DanByström Please check the answer I wrote; I got the corresponding code by decompiling its .Net SDK source code through ILSpy(It is also by calling its C++ SDK).

Comment: Afraid I have nothing more to say here. I guess I would have made sure I could run this in C++ first. Then I could investigate the values passed using the C++ debugger and compare with what's going on in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct definitions are not correct:

- `Pack = 1` is unlikely to be correct. Packing is not usually specified, so it would normally go after the native pointer size.
- The `byte` values are actually fixed-length strings. You can use `UnmanagedType.ByValTStr` for that, along with `CharSet.Ansi`.
- `fixed` buffers need `unsafe`, but you can just use three values instead.

---

```
[DllImport("MvCodeReaderCtrl.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.CDecl)]
public static extern Int32 MV_CODEREADER_EnumDevices(ref MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST pstDevList, UInt32 nTLayerType);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_USB3_DEVICE_INFO
{
    public byte CrtlInEndPoint;
    public byte CrtlOutEndPoint;
    public byte StreamEndPoint;
    public byte EventEndPoint;
    public UInt16 idVendor;
    public UInt16 idProduct;
    public uint nDeviceNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chDeviceGUID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chVendorName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chModelName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chFamilyName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chDeviceVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chManufacturerName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chSerialNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
    public string chUserDefinedName;
    public uint nbcdUSB;
    public uint nReserved1;
    public uint nReserved2;
    public uint nReserved3;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_GIGE_DEVICE_INFO
{
    public UInt32 nIpCfgOption;
    public UInt32 nIpCfgCurrent;
    public UInt32 nCurrentIp;
    public UInt32 nCurrentSubNetMask;
    public UInt32 nDefultGateWay;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string chManufacturerName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string chModelName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string chDeviceVersion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 48)]
    public string chManufacturerSpecificInfo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string chSerialNumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string chUserDefinedName;
    public UInt32 nNetExport;
    public UInt32 nCurUserIP;
    public uint nReserved1;
    public uint nReserved2;
    public uint nReserved3;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO
{
    public UInt16 nMajorVer;
    public UInt16 nMinorVer;
    public uint nMacAddrHigh;
    public uint nMacAddrLow;
    public uint nTLayerType;
    public uint nReserved1;
    public uint nReserved2;
    public uint nReserved3;
    public MV_CODEREADER_GIGE_DEVICE_INFO stGigEInfo;
    public MV_CODEREADER_USB3_DEVICE_INFO stUsb3VInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST
{
    public UInt32 nDeviceNum;
    public MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO[] pDeviceInfo;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When the program runs, it exists immediately without any errors again.

Comment: You probably also need to set the calling convention to CDecl, see edits

Comment: I just tested about it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The hardware also provides a .Net SDK which made by .Net Framework 2.0

However, .Net 7 cannot reference its .Net Framework 2.0 SDK and the hardware manufacturer refuses to provide SDK support .Net Core or .Net Standard.

Then I had a strange idea by using ILSpy to decompile its .Net Framework 2.0 SDK.

Well, its .Net SDK just happens to be implemented by calling their C++ SDK through P/Invoke.

And here is its official code (In fact, some places cannot correspond to their C++ SDK).

Here are its code and it runs successfully:

```
[DllImport("MvCodeReaderCtrl.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 MV_CODEREADER_EnumDevices(ref MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST pstDevList, UInt32 nTLayerType);
        
        public struct MV_CODEREADER_USB3_DEVICE_INFO
        {
            public byte CrtlInEndPoint;
            public byte CrtlOutEndPoint;              
            public byte StreamEndPoint;
            public byte EventEndPoint;
            public ushort idVendor;
            public ushort idProduct;
            public uint nDeviceNumber;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chDeviceGUID;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chVendorName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chModelName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chFamilyName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chDeviceVersion;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chManufacturerName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chSerialNumber;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 64)]
            public string chUserDefinedName;
            public uint nbcdUSB;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public uint[] nReserved;
        }
       
        public struct MV_CODEREADER_GIGE_DEVICE_INFO
        {          
            public uint nIpCfgOption;          
            public uint nIpCfgCurrent;
            public uint nCurrentIp;
            public uint nCurrentSubNetMask;
            public uint nDefultGateWay;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string chManufacturerName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string chModelName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string chDeviceVersion;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 48)]
            public string chManufacturerSpecificInfo;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
            public string chSerialNumber;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
            public string chUserDefinedName;
            public uint nNetExport;
            public uint nCurUserIP;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
            public uint[] nReserved;
        }
        
        public struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 540)]
            public struct SPECIAL_INFO
            {                
                [FieldOffset(0)]
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 216)]
                public byte[] stGigEInfo;
                [FieldOffset(0)]
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 540)]
                public byte[] stUsb3VInfo;
            }
        public ushort nMajorVer;
        public ushort nMinorVer;
        public uint nMacAddrHigh;
        public uint nMacAddrLow;
        public uint nTLayerType;
        public bool bSelectDevice;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
        public uint[] nReserved;
        public SPECIAL_INFO SpecialInfo;
    }
    
    public struct MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO_LIST
    {            
        public uint nDeviceNum;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 256)]
        public IntPtr[] pDeviceInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm so the last two fields in `MV_CODEREADER_DEVICE_INFO` are a union struct, that's not in the documentation

Comment: @Charlieface This is exactly the strange thing that I mentioned in my answer that it cannot correspond to the provided C++ SDK documentation.